# How to efficiently wait for an external task to finish while Spark is working?

Tags: apache-spark

I have the following problem: there is a large CSV file which we read with spark. We need to transform each line of the file and write it back to another text file. During this transformation, we need to invoke an external service via REST and before we write the file, we need to get the answer back from the service. In the meantime, we can do other actions on Spark.

A naive implementation would look like this:

```
val keys = spark.read.csv("/path/to/myfile.csv")
    .map(row => {
       val result = new Param(row(0), row(3), row(7))
       result
    })
    .collect()

val enrichedData: Map[String,String] = keys.map(key => 
      externalService.getValue(key))  // unpredictable response time

val finalResult = spark.read.csv("/path/to/myfile.csv")  // read same file twice
    .map(row => doSomeTransformation(row))
    .map(row => doSomeMoreTransformation(row))
    .map(row => andAnotherCostlyOperation(row))
    .map(row => {
        val key = row(0)
        val myData = enrichedData(key)  // only here we use the data from ext.serv.
        enrichRow(row, myData)
    })
    .write.csv("/path/to/output.csv")
```

The problem here is that I'm reading the same input file twice. First I need to collect all the keys from the file and send them to the external service. Once the external service responds, I can go over the same file again and use the data I've obtained to finish processing the data.

How to do this more efficiently? I don't really need the data from the external service until the very last step, so it would be nice if Spark could do the other transformations in parallel, and then when it reaches the last map() function, it would wait (potentially 0 sec) for the data from the external service.

Comment: how about invoking an external service while creating "finalResult", i.e. without preparing "enrichedData" beforehand?

Comment: The problem is that if I invoke the external service, it can take a long time to get back a response. So if I invoke it in the end when creating finalResult, it could block the whole process. It would be a more efficient use of time to invoke the service at the beginning, do all the other work in the meantime, and in the end collect the result from the external service.